# change array consist of coordinate(x,y) to string

Tags: python, arrays, arraylist, arduino, path-finding

i have path planning project with python and the result is array consist of coordinate(x,y) like this:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3)]
```

since I want to send that data to arduino to control the movement of the AGV, I have to convert the array above to this format:

```
{0.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3}
```

how to do this with python code???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate the list and get the rquired float values either by f-string, or by numeric calculation i.e. x+y/10, you can do this in a List Comprehension

```py
# d is the list of tuples that you have in question
>>> [float(f"{x}.{y}") for x,y in d]

[0.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3]

#or
>>> [x+y/10 for x,y in d]

[0.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3]
```

on a side note, the output you have mentioned is set which may not necessarily preserve the order that's why I've created list as final result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `map` function to do this easily. Here in the second line of my code, a `lambda` function is used to take one item from the `num` list and convert it to the desired form.

```
num = [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3)]

float_num = list(map(lambda x: x[0] + x[1] / 10, num))

#printing the results
print(float_num)
```